# Version of Taylor: $F(x+h)-F(x) = \left \langle \int_0^1 \nabla F(x+th)dt, h \right \rangle.$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

My teacher claimed without proof that Taylor's theorem with remainder implied that for a suitable function $F: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$,
$$F(x+h)-F(x) = \left \langle \int_0^1 \nabla F(x+th)dt, h \right \rangle.$$

Can someone provide me an indication of why this is so? What is this version of the remainder?

Answer (score 3):

$$F(x+h)-F(x)=\int_0^1\frac{d}{dt}F(x+th)\,dt=\cdots$$

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why we need to use Taylor here. By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, $G(1)-G(0)=\int_{0}^{1} G^{\prime}(t)dt$. Define $G(t)=F(x+t\cdot h)$ then $G^\prime=\nabla F\cdot h$.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a convenient expression for $G''(t)$? I believe it should be $\langle H(x+th)h, h \rangle$, where $H$ is the Hessian.

Comment: $G^{\prime\prime} =h^t \cdot \nabla^2 F \cdot h$ where $\nabla^2 F$ is the Hessian matrix of $F$ and $h^t$ means the transpose of $h$.